# Linq to Entities - where statement throws System.NotSupported Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
   var entity =
   from document in db.Context.DocumentEntity
   join product in db.Context.ProductEntity on document.ProductId equals product.Id
   join partner in db.Context.PartnerEntity on product.PartnerId equals partner.Id
   select new
   {
       document,
       product,
       partner
   } into t1
   where request.PartnerFilter.Contains(t1.partner.Name)
   group t1 by t1.document.Date into rp
   select new
   {
       PartnerName = rp.FirstOrDefault().partner.Name,
       Date = rp.FirstOrDefault().document.Date,
       Income = rp.Sum(x => x.document.Income),
       Click= rp.Sum(x => x.document.Click)
   };

result = ToDataTable(entity.OrderByDescending(d=>d.Date).ToList());


public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
{
  DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

  PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
  foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
  {
    var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);
    dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
  }
  foreach (T item in items)
  {
    var values = new object[Props.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
    {
        values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
    }
    dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
  }
 return dataTable;
```

}

The problem is on where clause. `request.PartnerFilter` is a string array and might be null. I need to check if `partner.Name` is included in it. Kind of Sql Where-In. In the end entity.ToList() throws System.NotSupported Exception. How can I accomplish to filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `Contains` inside the EF query expression tree, you need to ensure the variable is not null. And you need to do that (along with the condition if it needs to be applied) outside the query.

For instance:

```
var partnerFilter = request.PartnerFilter ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>();
bool applyPartnerFilter = partnerFilter.Any();

var entity =
    ...
    where (!applyPartnerFilter || partnerFilter.Contains(t1.partner.Name))
    ...
```

But in my opinion it would be much better to apply the optional filter(s) outside the query, for instance:

```
var partners = db.Context.PartnerEntity.AsQueryable();
if (request.PartnerFilter != null && request.PartnerFilter.Any())
    partners = partners.Where(partner => request.PartnerFilter.Contains(partner.Name));

var entity =
...
join partner in partners on product.PartnerId equals partner.Id
...
```

(no `where`)

Comment: Great. Solved the problem and learned how to use Contains in EF

Answer (score 2):

Take this request part out of the equation because Entity Framework doesn't know what to do with a Request object, it can handle strings, string arrays, etc.

```
string[] strArray=request.PartnerFilter;

var entity =
from document in db.Context.DocumentEntity
join product in db.Context.ProductEntity on document.ProductId equals product.Id
join partner in db.Context.PartnerEntity on product.PartnerId equals partner.Id
select new
{
   document,
   product,
   partner
} into t1
//Check if null
where strArray!=null && strArray.Any() && strArray.Contains(t1.partner.Name)
group t1 by t1.document.Date into rp
select new
{
   PartnerName = rp.FirstOrDefault().partner.Name,
   Date = rp.FirstOrDefault().document.Date,
   Income = rp.Sum(x => x.document.Income),
   Click= rp.Sum(x => x.document.Click)
};
```

Also, use Navigation Properties instead of joins

Comment: Same happened. didn't make any difference. Problem might be with null check. I used turnery operator.

Comment: Updated answer, pls try again

Comment: I've added an item into strArray and it worked whereas if it's null still same. Any way to put entire where statement into if condition(including where key word)

Answer (score 1):

You use the SQL `WHERE IN ()` Clause with `Contains` correct. Your only problem is the possible null exception.

What should happen if the array is empty? Would you like to have all the values? Use `true` if array is null otherwise `false`

Try this:

```
string[] partnerNames = request.PartnerFilter;

var entity =
   from document in db.Context.DocumentEntity
   join product in db.Context.ProductEntity on document.ProductId equals product.Id
   join partner in db.Context.PartnerEntity on product.PartnerId equals partner.Id
   select new
   {
       document,
       product,
       partner
   } into t1
   where partnerNames?.Contains(t1.partner.Name) ?? true
   group t1 by t1.document.Date into rp
   select new
   {
       PartnerName = rp.FirstOrDefault().partner.Name,
       Date = rp.FirstOrDefault().document.Date,
       Income = rp.Sum(x => x.document.Income),
       Click= rp.Sum(x => x.document.Click)
   };
```

**WHERE IN - as query Syntax**

```
var selected = from document in Document 
               where new[] {"Paul", "Peter"}.Contains(document.UserName)
               select document
```

**WHERE IN - as method Syntax**

```
var selected = Document
               .Where(d => new[] ["Paul","Peter"}.Contains(d.UserName))
```

Comment: I did `request.PartnerFilter!= null ? request.PartnerFilter.Contains(t1.partner.Name) : true`. entity.ToList() in the VS watch statement still throws same error. If I keep debugging, results as: Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.String[]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context

Comment: Can you use an initialized empty list with `.Any()` check?

Comment: I've tried this: `List<string> list = new List<string>(); list.Add("");` and `where list.Any()`. It's working